# Android access to folder is only granted until app is closed

Tags: java, android

When my app is launched for the first time and the Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE is called then I choose my desired folder in file explorer, my code works fine until I do "Force close app". After that I get an en exception (`dfFinalDir` is null):

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile.findFile(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

I guess it happens maybe because after closing the app I lose my access to folder, but shouldn't it be permanently? I hope so and this is what I want to achieve.

```
private void writeDataToFile(Intent intent) {

    String uriString = sp.getString("auto_backup_uri", "");

    if (uriString.equals("")) {
        Util.initConfirmDialog(this, getString(R.string.choose_folder_for_auto_backup) + getString(R.string.app_name_no_space) + "/", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Log.i("TAG", "Trying to get access the desired folder");
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                startActivityForResult(intent2, AppConstants.GRANT_ACCESS_TO_AUTO_BACKUP_FILE);
            }
        });
    }

    if (!uriString.equals("")) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Trying to write data to file " + uriString);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
        DocumentFile dfBeforeFinalDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri);
        DocumentFile dfFinalDir = dfBeforeFinalDir.findFile(getString(R.string.app_name_no_space));

        // HERE IS AN EXCEPTION
        DocumentFile dfFinalAutoBackupFile = dfFinalDir.findFile("notatki_a");


        if (dfFinalAutoBackupFile == null) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Auto backup file does not exist, creating new one");
            dfFinalAutoBackupFile = dfFinalDir.createFile("application/*", "notatki_a");
        }

        OutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try {
            fileOutputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(dfFinalAutoBackupFile.getUri());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            doWhenException(e, "The provided URI could not be opened", intent);
        }
        try {
            fileOutputStream.write(jsonNotes.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            fileOutputStream.close();
            intent.putExtra("auto_save_status", AppConstants.SUCCESS);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            doWhenException(e, "An IOException during writing data to newly created file", intent);
        } finally {
            if (extNoteOrder > 0)
                intent.putExtra("ext_note_order", extNoteOrder);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
    if (requestCode == AppConstants.GRANT_ACCESS_TO_AUTO_BACKUP_FILE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (resultData != null) {
            Uri uri = resultData.getData();
            spEditor.putString("auto_backup_uri", uri.toString()).apply();

            DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri);

            try {
                DocumentFile dfFinalDir = documentFile.findFile(getString(R.string.app_name_no_space));
                if (dfFinalDir == null) {
                    dfFinalDir = documentFile.createDirectory(getString(R.string.app_name_no_space));
                }
                if (dfFinalDir != null) {
                    Util.initConfirmDialogNoNegButton(this, getString(R.string.you_can_do_with_auto_backup));
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Util.doWhenException(this, e, "The problem with /" + getString(R.string.app_name_no_space) + "/ folder: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

private void doWhenException(Exception e, String exCause, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("TAG", exCause);
    Toast.makeText(ActivityNewEditNote.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
    intent.putExtra("auto_save_status", AppConstants.FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: dfFinalDir==null but you are not checking it before use hence the null pointer exception. Know what goes wrong first.

Comment: If you analyze this code you know that it never should be null, because earlier everything is set straightforwardly. It is all about keeping access to this folder when onDestroy and later onCreate is called, then it will not be null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `takePersistableUriPermission()` to keep access across runs without re-asking the user to choose the directory.

See [Persist permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions) for details on how to do this.

Comment: Alright thank you, I will test this solución  tommorow and accept if it works.